# Find same position in two strings that are slightly different

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I have two strings where the first is a *master* string and the second is a *slave* string. They both contain similar values except that the *slave* will have characters added or removed.

I need to find the character offset from the *master* string in the *slave* string for each character of the *master* string.

I'm currently using a *percentage* as the algorithm for finding the similar offset in the *slave* string.

For example;

```
const master = 'The chicken is blue, but not really a chicken';
const slave = 'This large bird is blue, but is really a dog';

function slaveOffset(m, offset, s): number {
    return Math.floor(s.length * (offset / m.length));
}

console.log(slaveOffset(master, 15, slave)); // prints 12
```

When translating the position 15 from the master (which reads "The chicken is ") the slave position is calculated as 12. Which reads as "This large b" because using percentage is not at all accurate (doesn't take into account added or removed characters).

The correct value should have been 18 (which reads as "The large bird is"), because the master offset ends at "is".

I need an algorithm for `slaveOffset()` that can handle added and removed characters and find the most likely slave offset. It does not need to be overly accurate but should solve the problem of large deviations caused by character changes.

Comment: What’s the real content of your strings? Does [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance) help?

Comment: @Ry- the strings hold HTML where the *slave* has been cleaned and had `<!-- --->` comments inserted. Yes, the Levenshtein Distance might help. I'm looking at it now.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé I think it should have been 18 so that `slave.substring(0, 18) === "The large bird is"`

Comment: if I had to solve this problem, I would put each word on a line and use the [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) utility

Comment: Is it for use on large strings ? Is time complexity important for your algo ?

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé I'm not worried about performance. The strings are relatively small (500 or so words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem in computer science, typically called "data comparison" or simply "diff". The most common algorithms apply [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) techniques, but in the general case this is a NP-hard problem so various heuristics are applied to get a "good enough" outcome, often tuned by a human in the loop.

Look up some `diff` algorithms to get some ideas.

In your case you probably want to start with the heuristic of "where does the slave string start to differ from the master and where does it become the same again". The strings match for the first two characters, but the next time you get a sequence of more than 3 characters matching is at the characters , `i` and `s`. The points become markers that you can use in your `slaveOffset` function.

Comment: I ended up using a diff function and that provided enough data to rewrite how I was handling this. I used this npm package https://github.com/jhchen/fast-diff